# Javascript To Do List

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I am trying to make a to-do list app and am trying to add a clickable checkbox next to each item as it is added to the list. I am very new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

```js
   function todoList() {
      var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value
      var text = document.createTextNode(item)
      var newItem = document.createElement("li")
      newItem.appendChild(text)
     document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)
    }
```

```html
  <form id="todoForm">
      <h1>To Do List:<h1>
        <input id="todoInput">
        <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Item</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="todoList">
    </ul>
```

Comment: what is problem ??

Comment: It would seem you already know how to create and append elements in a general sense (the code you've shown works), so what is giving you trouble when it comes to checkboxes? (You want the checkboxes inside the new li elements, right? So create one and append to `newItem`.)

Comment: I guess I was not sure what all needed to be added such as the type, name, and value etc. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Javscript**

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/vuy58yka/1/)

```
function todoList() {
      var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value
      var text = document.createTextNode(item)
      var newItem = document.createElement("li")
      newItem.appendChild(text)
      var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = "name";
            checkbox.value = "value";
            checkbox.id = "id";
            newItem.appendChild(checkbox);
     document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help from the comment and example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to add checkbox, instead of the bullets. The below code does that. If you want to learn more about creating "Todo list" apps, then take inspiration from [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/)

```js
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(item);
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.name = "name";
  checkbox.value = "value";
  var newItem = document.createElement("div");
  
  newItem.appendChild(checkbox);
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <form id="todoForm">
  <h1>To Do List:<h1>
    <input id="todoInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Item</button>
</form>
<div id="todoList">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. I will check out that link here shortly. Thanks again.